# How to select/model last customer status in any given period SSAS

Tags: ssas, history, mdx, status

I'm trying to model the following situation in SSAS.
I have three dimensions:
Customers
id
1
2

Statuses
id name
1  status_1
2  status_2

Dates
day_date
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
...

And, there is FactCustomerStatuses table
customer_id, status_id, day_date
1            1          2012-01-01
1            2          2012-03-01
1            1          2012-05-01

Having this, I built a simple cube with these dimensions and count measure.
Now, I want a report which will show # of customers me for any given date with respect to latest status for any customer for that date. For example, I do report on 2012-02-01, and I have there (with given example) 1 customer in status_1, 0 customers in status_2.
when I do the report on 2012-04-01, I have 0 customers in status_1 and 1 customer in status_2. And then this customer migrates again to status_1, and so on.
How could I accomplish the task either with data model or with MDX? I can build a snapshot with latest status for every customer, but it will give me only current state of the customers database. but I want to compare it with, say, yesterdays state, or what was a month ago or whenever.
Could anybody give some clues?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer based on comments below

Try this Oleksandr

```
  WITH  MEMBER Measures.CountCustomer AS DistinctCount([Customer].[Customer].Children)
SELECT  NON EMPTY {   Measures.CountCustomer } ON COLUMNS ,
        [Status].[Status].Children ON ROWS
FROM 
( 
    SELECT null:[status Date].[Status Day Date].&[2012-03-01T00:00:00] ON COLUMNS
    FROM TestStatus
)
```

Comment: that is not what I want. In the given query instead of 0 I want to look up the latest available status for a given date.

Comment: In your question you state that you want to see " I do report on 2012-02-01, and I have 1 customer in status_1, 0 customers in status_2".  Is the 0 customers in status_2 section incorrect? Can you revise the question to state the real expected report output and I'll try to help you solve it

Comment: Probably, my explanation of the overall idea is not very good. But, if you pay attention to dates in Fact tables the first date is 2012-01-01, the next date for this customer is 2012-03-01. Now, I run report on 2012-02-01, which is between these dates from fact table. indeed, I see that there is one customer in the database, but what was his/her status on 2012-02-01? Your query will return 0 for both status_1 and status_2, but the latest status for 2012-02-01 is status_1. So, I want to look up from 2012-02-01 in the past and grab the latest status for this customer.

Comment: Okay, I think that I understand.  So for each date entered you want the last customer status, before or on that date - is that correct?  What do you expect to happen when there are multiple customer status changes (with different status values) on a single date - do you want a distinct list of latest status values or the highest?  is it just the latest status value you are interested in, or do you want the related customers as well?

Comment: that is barely possible to have multiple statuses on 1 day for the same customer. So this is not necessary to consider. I'm interested in # of customers per latest status for any reporting day I choose. Basically, I would like to have dates in rows, statuses in columns, and on their intersections will be counts of customers per latest available status for the corresponding date.

Comment: Here is pure SQL to solve the problem SELECT
 t.[last_status]
 ,COUNT(t.[customer_id])
FROM (
SELECT
 r.[customer_id]
 ,(SELECT TOP 1 l.[status_id] 
  FROM [dwh].[dbo].[fact_customers_statuses] l 
  WHERE l.[customer_id] = r.[customer_id] AND l.status_id IN (1, 2) AND l.status_day_date < '2012-02-01' 
  ORDER BY l.status_day_date DESC) AS [last_status]
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT
  f.[customer_id]
 FROM [dwh].[dbo].[fact_customers_statuses] f
 WHERE
  f.status_day_date <= '2012-02-01' AND f.status_id IN (1, 2)) AS r) AS t
WHERE 
 t.[last_status] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
 t.[last_status]